# LaTeX to IMG in Embarcadero Delphi

Tags: chromium, delphi

I search for FMX tool to convert LaTeX formulas in images. Excellent TTMSFNCWXMathEditor component of TMS allow to edit formula in editor window based on Chromium Edge browser. It is possible to access, via Java commands, to Chromium framework to convert formula without go through editor window? I don't find any documentation for this.